# Equaly space buttons on grid using css

Tags: html, css

I'm building a multi column/multi line button pad with limited vertical spacing. Here is the code:

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qrtbmow8/)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  height: 30px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.button-line {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.button-line button {
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button-line button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="title">
    OPTIONS
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button-line">
      <div class="button">
        <button>TEST BUTTON 1</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-line">
      <div class="button">
        <button>TEST BUTTON 2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>TEST BUTTON 3</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-line">
      <div class="button">
        <button>TEST BUTTON 4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My buttons are not applying padding between the lines and between the buttons, showing buttons over buttons. I need line spacing and button spacing between then. all centered.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You were forcing an explicit `height: 100px;` on `.buttons`, you should remove it. If you need to maintain that height but you want the contents of `.buttons` to be scrollable you can remove `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;`. Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gnhb9Lu7/3/

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  height: 30px;
}

.buttons {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.button-line {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.button-line button {
  width: 100%;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button-line button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="title">
    OPTIONS
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="button-line">
      <div class="button">
        <button>TEST BUTTON 1</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-line">
      <div class="button">
        <button>TEST BUTTON 2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        <button>TEST BUTTON 3</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-line">
      <div class="button">
        <button>TEST BUTTON 4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the issue... I can't remove this height, as I have limite spacing for these buttons and it can't go high that a given height (100px in that case). I need to scroll the buttons.

Comment: @Mendes I've update my answer, please take a second look.